# ¿Control en bucles e if?

Tags: javascript

Estoy armando una especie de Rol Narrado usando Javascript.

Utilizo un `<input id="dialogo" type="text">` para colocar nuestras respuestas en torno a la situación que se esta atravesando en la "Aventura".

Tomo los datos del `<input>` cuando el usuario apreta el "Enter".

```
var dialogo = document.querySelector('#dialogo');
dialogo.addEventListener('keydown', ComprueboDatos)


function ComprueboDatos(){

    var tecla = event.key;

    if(tecla == 'Enter'){ //Trate de poner 13 pero no me lo toma. (ASCII ENTER)
        if(dialogo.value == "aventura"){
           dialogo.value = ''
           IniciaAventura()
        }
        else{
            consola.innerHTML = "No entendi lo que me dijiste."
            dialogo.value = ''
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora, cuando quiero confirmar si realmente quiere iniciarla, la idea es volver a escribir en el `<input>` "si" y que inicie.

```
function IniciaAventura() {

    if(dialogo.value == 'si'){
        consola.innerHTML = "Empezemos a explorar";

        setTimeout(AventuraNro1, 2000);
    }
     if (dialogo.value == 'no') {

        CancelaAventura();
     } 
     else{
        consola.innerHTML = "Vuelve cuando estes preparado."
     }
}
```

Pero obviamente tengo 2 casos:

- Uno es que seteo `dialogo = ''` para borrar el contenido que se halla escrito.
- Y segundo que es todo lineal. Por mas que le escriba "aventura", me inicia la "aventura", pasa el `dialogo` vació sin dejarme ami opción de decidir y desemboca en un else.

## Mi pregunta

¿Como puedo hacer para tener mas control dentro de los bucles y los if en casos similares?

Este ejemplo que mostré no es tanto el problema, pero imagínense cuando tenga que empezar a describirle al usuario si decide ir al este o al oeste u otro tipo de acciones escritas.

Necesitaría usar constantemente el `<input>` y que este me responda en el lugar que yo lo solicito.

## Extra:

Investigue de usar los Break y Continue, pero no halle solución con esos comandos.

Espero halla sido claro, espero puedan darme una mano para ir orientándome mejor.

Es mi primer proyecto grande con HTML,CSS/Sass/JS/Gulp/PHP/MySQL asi que seguro cuando vuelva a caer al pozo vuelva a preguntar nuevamente.

Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claro que puedes usar tu `input` para ambas cosas:

Lo único que hice fue remover el evento `ComprueboDatos()` del `input` para que al presionar `enter` no lo volviera a ejecutar y añadirle uno nuevo, el que se usaría para confirmar.

**NOTA:** si quieres capturar la tecla por su código y no por su nombre entonces debes usar [event.keyCode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp)

```js
var consola = document.querySelector('#consola');
var dialogo = document.querySelector('#dialogo');
dialogo.addEventListener('keydown', ComprueboDatos);


function ComprueboDatos(){
    var tecla = event.keyCode;

    if(tecla == 13){
        if(dialogo.value == "aventura"){
           dialogo.value = ''

           consola.innerHTML = "¿Estás preparado?"

           dialogo.removeEventListener('keydown', ComprueboDatos);
           dialogo.addEventListener('keydown', IniciaAventura);
        }
        else{
            consola.innerHTML = "No entendi lo que me dijiste."
            dialogo.value = ''
        }
    }
}

function IniciaAventura() {
    var tecla = event.keyCode;

    if(tecla == 13){
        if(dialogo.value == 'si'){
            consola.innerHTML = "Empezemos a explorar";

            setTimeout(AventuraNro1, 2000);
        }else if (dialogo.value == 'no') {
            consola.innerHTML = "Vuelve cuando estes preparado."

            CancelaAventura();
        }else{
            consola.innerHTML = "No entendi lo que me dijiste. <br> ¿Estás preparado?"
            dialogo.value = ''
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="" name="" id="dialogo">
<div id="consola"></div>
```

Comment: Una lagrima callo sobre el teclado. Gracias :) hoy temprano estuve leyendo acerca de removeEventListener. Muy amable!.

Agrego: gracias también por lo del keyCode. Ya me quedo claro.

Comment: Cuando necesites algo más no dudes en preguntar ;)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que buscas es utilizar el método `confirm`. De esta manera, le podrás mostrar al usuario una pregunta y el podrá contestar "Aceptar" o "Cancelar" y, dependiendo de la respuesta que este seleccione, ejecutar un código u otro.

Ejemplo:

```js
if(confirm('¿Estás seguro de que quieres continuar por ese camino?')) {
    console.log("Ha dicho que si");
}
else {
    console.log("Ha dicho que no");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, voy a probar como quedaria, pero se me hace chocante tener constantemente una ventana emergente a la que clikear. 

Quise implementar este "sistema" del input, para que simplemente el usuario no tenga que tocar el mouse mas que para moverse por los submenus del juego, asi borrando varios botones como "Sur" "Norte",etc..